# How to make radiobutton using key-value pairs in rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

For dropdown values in rails we can write like key-value pairs. For example

```
  <div class="custom-dropdown big">
        <%= f.select  :product_type, [["Car","Car"], ["Bus","Bus"], ["Truck","Truck"],["Flight","Flight"], ["Train","Train"], ["Ship","Ship"],
                                   ["other","other"]], id: "product_type", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
```

But how can we do the same with radio buttons?? For eg. lets say we have few radio buttons like this..

```
<div class="segmented-control" style="width: 100%; color: #5FBAAC">
            <input type="radio" name="pieces" id="1">
            <input type="radio" name="pieces" id="2">
            <input type="radio" name="pieces" id="3">
            <input type="radio" name="pieces" id="4">
            <input type="radio" name="pieces" id="5">
            <input type="radio" name="pieces" id="6">

            <label for="1"  data-value="1">1</label>
            <label for="2" data-value="2">2</label>
            <label for="3" data-value="3">3</label>
            <label for="4"  data-value="4">4</label>
            <label for="5" data-value="5">5</label>
            <label for="6" data-value="6 or more">6</label>
 </div>
```

Could someone tell me how to achieve the same thing using rails?

Answer (score 1):

Try radio button collection:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :product_type, [["Car","Car"], ["Bus","Bus"], ["Truck","Truck"],["Flight","Flight"], ["Train","Train"], ["Ship","Ship"],
                                   ["other","other"]], :first, :last %>
```

Comment: what is the :first and :last here??

Comment: `:first`  indicates first element of array `:last` will be last element of array.
For eg: [["car","Car"]],  in this case first element is `car` which will be use as value of radio button and last element will be `Car` which will be label to display.

Answer (score 1):

> key-value pairs

What you have are *arrays* - [*key-value* pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair) are "hashes", and would appear as follows:

```
[
 {id: "1", name: "car"},
 {id: "2", name: "bus"},
 {id: "3", name: "truck"},
 {id: "4", name: "flight"},
 {id: "5", name: "train"},
 {id: "6", name: "ship"},
 {id: "7", name: "other"}
]
```

If you had the following, it would work:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @transports = [{id: "1", name: "car"},{id: "2", name: "bus"},{id: "3", name: "truck"},{id: "4", name: "flight"},{id: "5", name: "train"},{id: "6", name: "ship"},{id: "7", name: "other"}]
   end
end

#app/views/your_controller/index.html.erb
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :product_type, @transports, :id, :name %>
```

---

With your current setup, you should be able to use the following:

[`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @transports = [["Car","Car"],["Bus","Bus"],["Truck","Truck"],["Flight","Flight"],["Train","Train"],["Ship","Ship"],["other","other"]]
   end
end

#app/views/your_controller/index.html.erb
<%= f.select :product_type, options_for_select(@transports), id: "product_type", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control"  %>
```

Comment: The dropdown i provided in question is already working as expected. But the radiobutton(second code in question) is the one i asked for and still bit unclear as there is a data-value option int he html i provided...and yes i meant the arrays option and thought both were same...sorry for the confusion..I tried to change the `f.select` helper with  `f.collection_radio_buttons` but not working..

Comment: hmm. So what data are you trying to put into what? I didn't get your latter question at alllll tbh

Comment: I tried like this  `<%= f.collection_radio_buttons  :pieces, [["1","1"], ["2","2"], ["3","3"], ["4","4"],
    ["5","5"],["6","6"]], id: "pieces", class: "form-control" %>`

Comment: got an argument error "wrong number of arguments (3 for 4..6)"..seems like am missing some arguments

Comment: If you read the [`collection_radio_button` specs](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons), you'd see that you need to have the params set for your options: `<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :pieces, [["1","1"], ["2","2"], ["3","3"], ["4","4"], ["5","5"],["6","6"]], [0], [1], id: "pieces", class: "form-control" %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93378/discussion-between-abhilash-v-r-and-rich-peck).